# TS7053. implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'ZoneI'

Tags: typescript

```
interface ZoneI {
    code: string;
    name: string;
}

const dataList: ZoneI[] = [
    { code: 'C00', name: 'zone 00' },
    { code: 'C01', name: 'zone 01' },
    { code: 'C02', name: 'zone 02' },
    { code: 'C03', name: 'zone 03' }
]

findRow('code', 'C02')

function findRow(findRowBy: string, findRowValue: string) {
    // findRowBy='code'; findRowValue='C02'
    let row = dataList.find(c => c[findRowBy] === findRowValue)
}
```

ERROR: `ts7053  lement implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'ZoneI'. No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'ZoneI'.ts(7053)`

Comment: That's right; only two values could possibly work but you've allowed any string. Maybe `findRowBy: keyof ZoneI`?

Comment: Thanks jonrsharpe, now it is working fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell to ts compiler that `findRowBy` is key of a `ZoneI`

```
function findRow(findRowBy: string, findRowValue: string) {
    // findRowBy='code'; findRowValue='C02'
    let key = findRowBy as keyof ZoneI;
    let row = dataList.find(c => c[key] === findRowValue)
}
```

[Here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=6&ssc=17&pln=6&pc=22#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgFoHsQQJLIN4CwAUMqcgugCYQBcyAzmFKAOYDcxZyIcAtrQyasORAL7FiFEI2SU4YOABlgjOhizYA2gF1kAXmSbOZPOSoCA5AGEADDYsAabn0sAvTCjsXkoh8dKmFNR01jYAjI7O-CHuWMjh3r7%20%20GbByKEATJE80emxnlk%20fiQmqZa2AMzZLjEe8VU%20xNoSRDCglABK6ADuABQWQRCRmRYAlC0wAK4gCGDAmMhtIJ09vUsr3QBCAJ50jMwgLE7rXd0AanAANpMC%206yj%20MkA9E%20L7ac7egPmFmxvy6cLtcIF9bFlkpcIGBkABrCDbfT-DY7ZBweiw%20HoGBoDzYERcSHQqA9RFyBTKRgAOnWvQQ%20gAfORNHDtro9OykYCrjdxmIgA) is working sample.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just type the `findRowBy` parameter properly instead of using a type assertion, IE `(findRowBy: keyof ZoneI, findRowValue: string)`? This ensures correct usage and prevents the use of invalid values being passed and silently failing?

Comment: Yes your right that would be safe than my code. Thank you

Comment: The reason why i'm using type the findRowBy parameter, it is because I need to find row by 'code' and sometimes by 'name'. So I reuse the code.